# Publish project from cli

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface

I'm wondering what is the difference between publishing project from cli and from Visual Studio.
I just experienced sometimes publishing from cli is not getting latest changes. I mean when we have a change or new method, after publishing the project it is not visible. But if I publish from VisualStudio everything is ok.
I'm using this command for cli. I have different apis to publish individuality.

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o "D:\Deploy\Test\test.api\" "D:\Development\Test\test.api\test.api.csproj"
```

Plus before that I clean and rebuild the project again from cli.

```
dotnet clean 'D:\Development\Test\test.api\test.api.sln' --force
dotnet build 'D:\Development\Test\test.api\test.api.sln' --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the same configuration (`-c Release`) for all the `dotnet` commands you run.

However, `dotnet publish` command should normally be enough to get the latest changes.
Is there any chance you're running the commands without actually saving the files after editing them (VS probably does that automatically when publishing)? Have you tried editing the files with other text editors/IDEs?

Comment: I almost checked every option. I saved the code. I restart the machine and etc. Still doing it. Something is wrong but I couldn't find it.